# Wrapping text around Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have problem with wrapping text around my `tikz` picture. The text pushes the picture down on the left side. The right side of the picture is just white blank space. Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{ffxfqq}{rgb}{1.,0.4980392156862745,0.}
    \definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1.,0.,0.}
    \definecolor{ttzzqq}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.}
    \definecolor{ffvvqq}{rgb}{1.,0.3333333333333333,0.}
    \definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
    \definecolor{ccqqqq}{rgb}{0.8,0.,0.}
    \definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
    \definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.0][line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
        \draw [color=cqcqcq,, xstep=0.2cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-0.1,-0.2) grid (1.01,1.9);
        \draw[->,color=black] (-0.1,0.) -- (1.01,0.);
        \foreach \x in {,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \draw[->,color=black] (0.,-0.2) -- (0.,1.9);
        \foreach \y in {,0.5,1.,1.5}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
        \clip(-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (1.01,1.9);
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.1:1.01] plot(\x,{(\x)*(1.0-(\x))});
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=ccqqqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.1:1.01] plot(\x,{4.0*(\x)*(1.0-(\x))^(2.0)});
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=qqqqff,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.1:1.01] plot(\x,{9.0*(\x)*(1.0-(\x))^(3.0)});
        \draw[line width=1.2pt,color=ffvvqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.1:1.01] plot(\x,{16.0*(\x)*(1.0-(\x))^(4.0)});
        \draw [color=ttzzqq](0.18243947642766176,0.3440435383967781) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{n=1}$};
        \draw [color=ffqqqq](0.16216842349125493,0.7017667929520731) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{ n=2}$};
        \draw [color=qqqqff](0.10058496467045104,1.1070148535690674) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{n=3}$};
        \draw [color=ffxfqq](0.06083458820803932,1.4072463768115956) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{n=4}$};
        \draw[color=cyan, line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.1:1.01] plot(\x,{25.0*(\x)*(1.0-(\x))^(5.0)});
        \draw [color=cyan](0.08687594115602958,1.7874779000541237) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathbf{n=5}$};
        \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.3436812232132522,-3.245895724337) node {$f$};
        \draw[color=ccqqqq] (-0.3793582763813274,-3.245895724337) node {$g$};
        \draw[color=qqqqff] (-0.17085601760685717,-3.245895724337) node {$h$};
        \draw[color=ffvvqq] (-0.09266767056643087,-3.245895724337) node {$p$};
        \draw[color=black] (-0.049229699988416246,-3.245895724337) node {$r$};
        \end{scriptsize}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example so people can run it and see the problem that you wish to be solved.

Comment: Your clip rectangle does not include enough room for everything after \begin{scriptsize}, and even if it did it looks wasteful.  BTW, Is this code being generated by another program?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Yes, I used GeoGebra to generate the codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here your code with [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), which can be used to customize axis ( ticks, grid, labels, legends, .....) simply with `key=value` syntax.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

    \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.,0.39,0.}
    \definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.8,0.,0.}
    \definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
    \definecolor{color4}{rgb}{1.,0.34,0.}
    \colorlet{color5}{cyan}

 \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,height=9cm,plotstyle/.style={line width=1.2pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.05:1.01}} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}   
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xmin=0, xmax=1,
 ymin=0,ymax=2,
 axis lines=middle,
 grid=major,
 xtick={0,0.2,...,1},
 ytick={0,0.5,...,2},
 enlargelimits={abs=5mm},
 xlabel={$x$},
 ylabel={$y$},
 xlabel style={below},
 ylabel style={left}]
  \addplot[plotstyle,color1] {(x)*(1.0-(x))}node[pos=0.4,above,font=\footnotesize]{$n=1$};
  \addplot[plotstyle,color2] {4.0*(x)*(1.0-(x))^(2.0)}node[pos=0.46,above,font=\footnotesize]{$n=2$};
  \addplot[plotstyle,color3] {9.0*(x)*(1.0-(x))^(3.0)}node[pos=0.53,above,font=\footnotesize]{$n=3$};
  \addplot[plotstyle,color4] {16.0*(x)*(1.0-(x))^(4.0)}node[pos=0.575,above,font=\footnotesize]{$n=4$};
  \addplot[plotstyle,color5] {25.0*(\x)*(1.0-(\x))^(5.0)}node[pos=0.61,above,font=\footnotesize]{$n=5$};
     \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This really works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `{0pt}`as the last argument of `wrapfigure` works:

[image]

Comment: Bernard: Awesome.