# Place `tikzpicture` on the left of the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, luatex, wrapfigure

### Background

I’d like to write a LuaLaTeX document for the Roman Catholic Liturgy of the Holy Week (from the Psalm Sunday through Easter Sunday). I do this in Slovak language ([here](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lit_scores/blob/3b47f5e2eda110142acb5ce5128214a39924ae73/ustd/Biela%20Sobota.pdf)’s a pdf that uses images for portions that include any kind of graphics, like scores or a cross; [here](https://owensborodiocese.org/wp-content/uploads/The-Easter-Vigil-Script.pdf)’s somewhat English version of that document)

I created the cross from the Paschal candle (Slovak version: page 3; English version: page 4), however, I could not place it on the left side of the accompanying text. I did this using `tikzpicture`.

### What I have Tried

I tried to use `multicols`, but this package does not support `tikzpicture` to be in a column.

Then I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321427/wrapping-text-around-tikz-picture/321451) question, so I tried to use `wrapfigure`, but I could not make it work.

### Problem Definition

When I use `wrapfigure`, the text that should be on the left of the cross, is aligned left as if the `tikzpicture` would not be there.

Also, the cross should be left-aligned (to the page left margin) and to the top margin.

The text’s first line should be moved to the top margin to let the top of the letter alpha be aligned with the top of the first line of the text.

Also, if the cross and text should be moved lower on the page (because the text before would end on the same page as the cross and its text), the cross and its text should be moved as low as needed, while the top of alpha and the top of the first line of the text should be still on the same ‘invisible line’

The placement of the text that should be on the right, might be connected with my custom commands which I use as paragraph styles, namely `\rubrics` and `prayer`.

Anyway, I don’t care *how* the problem is solved, however, the better the solution, the better.

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, portrait}

% Packages
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}       % For the language-specific stuff
\usepackage{bookmark}            % For bookmarks and to stop `hyperref` complaining
\usepackage{xcolor}              % For font colour
\usepackage{enumitem}            % For {enumerate} that can be resumed and referenced
\usepackage{tikz}                % For drawing graphics
\usepackage{wrapfig}             % For wraping figures/images/tikz

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\rubrics}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}\selectfont\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}\color{red!100}\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont{#1}\color{black!100}\normalsize\selectfont}%
\newcommand{\prayer}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}\color{black!100}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont{#1}\color{black!100}\normalsize\setlength{\parindent}{0em}\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}\selectfont\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}}%
\newcommand{\crossLetters}[1]{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont{\textbf{\color{black!100}{#1}}}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.01cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red, line width=1.6mm] (0,-9) node[below=10] {\crossLetters{Ω}} -- (0,0) -- (1,0) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{0}} node[below=10] {\crossLetters{0}} -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{Α}} -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{2}} node[below=10] {\crossLetters{2}} -- (-3,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \prayer{Kristus je ten istý včera i dnes.}

    \rubrics{(celebrant vrýva zvislú čiaru kríža)}

    \prayer{On je počiatok a koniec,}

    \rubrics{(kňaz vrýva vodorovnú čiaru kríža)}

    \prayer{Alfa}

    \rubrics{(nad zvislú čiaru kríža vrýva písmeno alfa)}

    \prayer{i Omega,}

    \rubrics{(pod zvislú čiaru kríža vrýva písmeno omega)}

    \prayer{Pán času}

    \rubrics{(do ľavého horného uhla kríža vrýva prvú číslicu letopočtu)}

    \prayer{i večnosti.}

    \rubrics{(do pravého horného uhla kríža vrýva druhú číslicu letopočtu)}

    \prayer{Jemu patrí sláva i moc}

    \rubrics{(do ľavého spodného uhla kríža vrýva tretiu číslicu letopočtu)}

    \prayer{po všetky veky vekov. Amen.}

    \rubrics{(do spodného pravého uhla kríža vrýva štvrtú číslicu letopočtu)}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: "I tried to use multicols, but this package does not support tikzpicture to be in a column." Really?

Comment: Or rather I could not make it work. What I did with `multicols` is: added `\usepackage{multicols}` and instead of pair `\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.01cm}` and `\end{wrapfigure}` typed `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}`. I get an error: `! Arithmetic overflow.\n<recently read> \baselineskip\nl.70  \end{multicols}`. Anyway, if you know a solution, we are welcome to help me out. You could solve it with `multicols` too. ;)

Comment: Why not try with two minipages?

Comment: @leandriis, as I am quite new to *TeX, I have never heard of minipages. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

As @marmot (let’s say) [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486254/place-tikzpicture-on-the-left-of-the-text#comment1229582_486254), the `multicols` indeed works with `tikzpicture`, however, at first I did not manage to make it work. After some trials and errors, I made it work in combination with some other tweaks.

In comparison with the MWE from the question, I made the following changes:

1. added `\usepackage{multicol}`;
2. modified the `\rubrics` and `\prayer` commands a bit to remove all paragraph formatting and leave only character formatting (i.e. font size and colour);
3. added `\setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}` to let the left column be narrower / let the columns width be different from each other; [1]
4. added `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}`;
5. added `\vfill\null\columnbreak`, which is needed to insert a column break; [2]
6. and I added 4 line breaks (`\\`) to 4 longer lines to make it look better. :)

[1] different column width: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384598/70043

[2] column break: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8687/70043

### Modified Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, portrait}

% Packages
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}       % For the language-specific stuff
\usepackage{bookmark}            % For bookmarks and to stop `hyperref` complaining
\usepackage{xcolor}              % For font colour
\usepackage{enumitem}            % For {enumerate} that can be resumed and referenced
\usepackage{tikz}                % For drawing graphics
\usepackage{wrapfig}             % For wraping figures/images/tikz
\usepackage{multicol}            % For columns layout

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\rubrics}[1]{\color{red!100}\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont{#1}}%
\newcommand{\prayer}[1]{\color{black!100}\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont{#1}}%
\newcommand{\crossLetters}[1]{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont{\textbf{\color{black!100}{#1}}}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red, line width=1.6mm] (0,-9) node[below=10] {\crossLetters{Ω}} -- (0,0) -- (1,0) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{0}} node[below=10] {\crossLetters{0}} -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{Α}} -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) node[above=10] {\crossLetters{2}} node[below=10] {\crossLetters{2}} -- (-3,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \vfill\null\columnbreak  % This whole line is needed to insert a column break

        \prayer{Kristus je ten istý včera i dnes.}

        \rubrics{(celebrant vrýva zvislú čiaru kríža)}

        \prayer{On je počiatok a koniec,}

        \rubrics{(kňaz vrýva vodorovnú čiaru kríža)}

        \prayer{Alfa}

        \rubrics{(nad zvislú čiaru kríža vrýva písmeno alfa)}

        \prayer{i Omega,}

        \rubrics{(pod zvislú čiaru kríža vrýva písmeno omega)}

        \prayer{Pán času}

        \rubrics{(do ľavého horného uhla kríža vrýva\\ prvú číslicu letopočtu)}

        \prayer{i večnosti.}

        \rubrics{(do pravého horného uhla kríža vrýva\\ druhú číslicu letopočtu)}

        \prayer{Jemu patrí sláva i moc}

        \rubrics{(do ľavého spodného uhla kríža vrýva\\ tretiu číslicu letopočtu)}

        \prayer{po všetky veky vekov. Amen.}

        \rubrics{(do spodného pravého uhla kríža vrýva\\ štvrtú číslicu letopočtu)}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple(-minded?) proposal. Make the margin on the left wider and put the picture as an overlay. (I am sorry, I cannot copy all these accented text in my editor so I stripped everything off but the parts relevant to make the point.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\geometry{a4paper, left=4in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, portrait}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,shift={([xshift=2in,yshift=2in]current page.west)}]
  \draw[red, line width=1.6mm] (0,-9) node[below=10] {$\Omega$} 
  -- (0,0) -- (1,0) node[above=10] {A} 
  node[below=10] {0} -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) 
  node[above=10] {A} -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) 
  node[above=10] {2} node[below=10] 
  {2} -- (-3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank for an alternative. Although it is a *partial* solution, it is good to know one could do this. Anyway, is there a way to locally override the margins? For as you can see, I’ve used `book` for `\documentclass`, therefore I need the margins set to a specific values and them to override them locally for this part of the book. Another problem is the placement of the cross—it should be the way I described in the question, though I think it could be *shifted* in the `tikzpicture` settings, but I am not sure if it could be set for even and odd pages in one command.

Comment: @tukusejssirs This can be done with the geometry package, which you are already using, see  e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154256/121799).